# how to add items in a nested list in python? from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, software-design

i am getting error-"IndexError: list index out of range" after entering the first nested listed

```
def add_hotel(name,n,ac,fb,tv,wifi,budget):
                room=[[]]
                room[2][1]=name

                if(n>0):
                    for i in range(2,n+2):
                                room[i][1]=1
                                if(ac=="y" or"Y"):
                                    room[i][2]="Air Conditioning"

                                else:
                                    room[i][2]="No Air Conditioning"
                                if(fb=="y" or "Y" ):
                                    room[i][3]="Free Breakfast"
                                else:
                                    room[i][3]="Free Breakfast Not Available"
                                if(tv=="y" or "Y"):
                                    room[i][4]="TV Available"
                                else:
                                    room[i][4]="No TV"
                                if(wifi=="y" or "Y"):
                                    room[i][5]="Wifi"
                                else: 
                                    room[i][5]="No Wifi"

                                room[i][5]=budget
                                print(room)
                print(room)
```

here n is number of rooms and i I'm initialising it from index 2 because I have  two predifined list entities.
i want my output to look like this-(n=2)

```
[[hayat,1,"No Air Conditioning","Free Breakfast Not available","No TV","Wifi",30],[hayat,2,"No Air Conditioning","Free Breakfast Not available","TV available","Wifi",50]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are using

```py
room[i][2]="Air Conditioning"
```

But there is no position `2` in `room[i]` list

#### What to do

You should use function `listname.append(val)`

```py
room[i].append("Air Conditioning")
```

#### Your code become

```py
def add_hotel(name,n,ac,fb,tv,wifi,budget):
                room=[]
                room_tmp=[name]

                if(n>0):
                    for i in range(2,n+2):




                                room_tmp.append(1)
                                if(ac=="y" or"Y"):
                                    room_tmp.append("Air Conditioning")

                                else:
                                    room_tmp.append("No Air Conditioning")
                                if(fb=="y" or "Y" ):
                                    room_tmp.append("Free Breakfast")
                                else:
                                    room_tmp.append("Free Breakfast Not Available")
                                if(tv=="y" or "Y"):
                                    room_tmp.append("TV Available")
                                else:
                                    room_tmp.append("No TV")
                                if(wifi=="y" or "Y"):
                                    room_tmp.append("Wifi")
                                else: 
                                    room_tmp.append("No Wifi")

                                room_tmp.append(budget)
                                room.append(room_tmp)
                                print(room)
                print(room)
```

I didn't got what you are doing still your answer will be like this